# How to use a variable in iosxr_config lines in ansible playbook

Tags: python, ansible

I want to use variable in iosxr_config lines in ansible playbook. I have tried the following code.

```
- hosts: 116.119.4.1
  connection: local
  vars:
    trapdests: []
  tasks:
    - name: show version
      register: command_out
      iosxr_command:
        commands: "sh ipv4 interface brief | include Loopback0"
    - debug:
        var: command_out.stdout
    - name: trapping the Loopback ip
      register: trapdests
      set_fact:
        trapdests: "{{[item.split()[1]]}}"
      with_items: "{{command_out.stdout_lines}}"
    - debug:
        var: trapdests
#  tasks:
    - name: enable PCEP
      iosxr_config:
        lines:
           - traffic-eng
           - pcc
           - source-address ipv4 "{{item}}"
           - pce address ipv4 100.67.249.67
           - precedence 100
        with_items: "{{trapdests}}"
        parents: segment-routing
```

Basically I want to use the variable at the end of this command---> source-address ipv4 "{{item}}". But I'm getting the following error:

```
TASK [enable PCEP] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [116.119.4.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/cisco/pcep_enble_test_2.yml': line 20, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n#  tasks:\n    - name: enable PCEP\n      ^ here\n"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/cisco/pcep_enble_test_2.retry

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
116.119.4.1                : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Can anybody help me out please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a syntax error. With_item have to be on task level:

```
- name: enable PCEP
  iosxr_config:
    lines:
      - traffic-eng
      - pcc
      - source-address ipv4 "{{ item }}"
      - pce address ipv4 100.67.249.67
      - precedence 100
    parents: segment-routing
  with_items: "{{ trapdests }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used like this - source-address ipv4 "{{trapdests[0]}}". But now I'm having another problem. I'm getting this error fatal: [116.119.4.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "source-address ipv4 \"116.119.4.1\"\r\n\r                                                                        ^\r\n% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.\r\nRP/0/RP0/CPU0:ATG-OR-CBC-T4-CR4.1(config-sr-te-pcc)#"} . I think I have to use the string without the double quotes("). I tried using - source-address ipv4 "{{trapdests[0].strip('"')}}". But still getting the same error. Please help.